# Why does std::add_lvalue_reference not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, type-traits, using-declaration

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using Ref1 = T & ;

template<typename T>
using Ref2 = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>;

template<typename T>
void f1(Ref1<T>)
{}

template<typename T>
void f2(Ref2<T>)
{}

int main()
{
    int n{};
    f1(n); // ok
    f2(n); // error
}
```

My compiler is clang 7.0, compiled with `c++17`. The error message is:

```
error : no matching function for call to 'f2'
  note: candidate template ignored:
        couldn't infer template argument 'T'
```

**Why is `f1` ok but `f2` isn't?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) is defined as `typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type`, then for `template<typename T> void f2(Ref2<T>)`, i.e. `template<typename T> void f2(typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type)`, belongs to [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), which causes template argument deduction fails.

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id: